# Disable field name localization

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, localization

I'm using a SharePoint team site in an international setting, and I would like the entire site to be in English. Unfortunately, when some columns titles and descriptions were changed, these changes applied only to some languages.

Thus, we have inconsistent field names and descriptions accross the board, which is *very* confusing.

Is there a way to disable this accidental and unwanted localization ?